# How change a file with 1 column to be a file with 2 columns

Tags: awk

I have a file with one column like this:

```
45
88
90
77
12
29
```

I want to change it to be like this:

```
45  88
90  77
12  29
```

How can I do it using `awk`?

Comment: This is not a free coding service. Please show what you have tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure your question looks the way you want it to in the question preview section. Without the edit you were essentially asking how to change an apple into an apple.

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' input
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%2 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
45 88
90 77
12 29
```

or if you understand awk fairly well you might prefer:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS)}1' file
45 88
90 77
12 29
```

Answer (score 2):

An awk version

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$0;getline;print $0}' file
```

Another version

```
awk 'NR%2 {printf "%s ",$0;next}1'
```

Comment: Don't use the getline version as you're inviting nasal demons (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline) for no good reason since it doesn't make the script briefer or otherwise improve it in any way compared to the non-getline version.

Comment: Thanks for info.  Will try to avoid getline

Answer (score 2):

I normally just use `xargs` for this kind of thing:

```
$ xargs -n2 < file
45 88
90 77
12 29
```

I scales nicely as you just change the value from 2 to the number of columns you want without having to rewrite a new script.

Comment: Nice alternative (btw, there is a typo: xrags instead of xargs).

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` version:

```
awk 'NR%2 == 1 { old = $0 }
     NR%2 == 0 { print old " " $0 }' file
```

Remember odd numbered lines in `old`; print the old value and the new value on even numbered lines.

Answer (score 1):

Or just simply use the shell:

```
while read A; do read B; echo "$A  $B"; done < file
```